# Java - Optimized way to find duplicates from two ArrayLists/Array

Tags: java

I have two Arrays/ArrayLists of Integer. I want to know the optmized way to find duplicates from two and store into the third one.

```
Array1 = {1,2,3,6,9,10,15,4};  
Array2 = {4,8,6,5,12,14,1,2,9};  
Result Array= {1,2,3,6,9,10,15,4,8,5,12,14,9}
```

Regards,
Android IT

Comment: Is there a limit on the values of the integers in the array (in addition to the 2^31 limit, of course?)

Comment: Are you sure you need optimization here? How much time your current implementation takes? More than 10ms?

Comment: Why is 9 in the output twice?

Comment: Sort. Merge. Erase duplicates.

Comment: What Fedor said.  Also you can't just say "optimized", you need to qualify what you are trying to optimize.  Are these lists going to have 10 elements each?  10 million?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer to use [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) over HashMap as HashMap need `key-value` & Sets talks about **UNIQUENESS**. **Sets don't allow duplicates...**

Answer (score 1):

Add elements of both arrays into a HashMap where the value is the number of times the element occurs. Then output it to an array.

Answer (score 1):

You mean, a set union?

```
List<Integer> array1 = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,6,9,10,15,4);
Set<Integer> set1 = new HashSet<Integer>(array1);

List<Integer> array2 = Arrays.asList(4,8,6,5,12,14,1,2,9);
Set<Integer> set2 = new HashSet<Integer>(array2);

set1.addAll(set2);
List<Integer> resultArray = new ArrayList<Integer>(set1);
```

Now `resultArray` contains

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15]
```

Answer (score 0):

The efficient way, sort the arrays (O(n log n)) and iterate through the lowest in both arrays and only select it if is in both (O(n)), otherwise discard.